# Can I tunnel all ports from remote server to 127.0.0.2 (for example), so work with it like with localhost

Tags: ssh, localhost, forwarding, tunnel

I have a remote server.

I started on remote server app that listen localhost only.

I want to tunnel this server to local ip like 127.0.0.2 and access this app through like I on remote server.

I need to tunnel all ports. Only one port is not what I search.

I tried to google ssh tunnel for it, but couldn't find.

Comment: Why do you need all ports? This sounds more like an X-Y problem to me.

Comment: I want to debug my app that used many dynamic ports.

Comment: Is it possible to do that via a socks proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Use a routable IP address. Not loopback. Access it remotely like a normal IP application.

For security, firewalls with default deny of TCP and UDP are a good idea, as usual. Allow rules for this could be restricted to smaller nets in some internal zone. Firewall rules can open a large range of ports, if that is needed. All ports is extraordinary, if I were firewall administrator I'd ask for you to restrict to a smaller range.

Depending on what this application is and what networks it needs to traverse, you may wish to tunnel or proxy in some way. Or leave it as localhost only, and require remoting into this host (such as with ssh) to access the thing running on its loopback.